# Azure Cognitive Service Translator Detect Language is broken

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-cognitive-services, translate

I wanted to use the "detect language" end point of the Translator Cognitive Service of Azure, but it seems broken to me. I've send a request to `https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/detect?api-version=3.0` with the following body:

```
[
    {"Text":"aoishdioashdoiashdioa"}
]
```

The response is:

```
[
    {
        "language": "en",
        "score": 1.0,
        "isTranslationSupported": true,
        "isTransliterationSupported": false,
        "alternatives": [
            {
                "language": "de",
                "score": 1.0,
                "isTranslationSupported": true,
                "isTransliterationSupported": false
            },
            {
                "language": "fr",
                "score": 1.0,
                "isTranslationSupported": true,
                "isTransliterationSupported": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm wondering how I can get such a high confidence score of 1.0 with my crappy input. Does anyone have an idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Seems you are trying in right way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a  neural system for microsoft-translator, so it's not easy to explain why you occur this situation.

However if you  insist on an explanation, here is a possible reason. When it's a invalid text, it will analysis the content what it has. Like your text all letters are all Latin script. And in many languages, they all contain these letters suppose that's why all score is 1.0 .

And then is about why it lists these languages, cause not all languages have same letters, like some have like `Ää`,`Žž`, suppose it will analysis the probability of these letters then get the highest probability languages list.